# How to nest using selenium elements C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, winappdriver

I've made a number of tests using `Selenium`. I was curious if I'm nesting correctly. I'm not sure if there is a better way and if there is I would be happy to hear it.

At the moment I open a PowerPoint session in my start up using the `WinApp` Driver. Then when nesting I do the following. Here I'm finding an element called Linking. A child of Linking in the tree of elements is Update and so on.

```
var linking = session.FindElementByName("Linking");
var update = linking.FindElementByName("Update");// within the linking element there is an update button
update.Click();
session.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
var all =update.FindElementByName("All");// within the update element there is a dropdown menu with an "All" button
session.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
all.Click();
```

[image]

Comment: Are you having problems with this? If not I think you can relax, it looks fine :) If there isn't a problem with this, this type of question is probably better for code review exchange

Comment: One thing to note, be very careful with `implicit` waits, they can easily lead to subtle bugs because you have to change them back to the default every time you change it to keep expected behavior.

Comment: @mrfreester Thanks for looking at my code. I am having some problems with it. It can find and locate the "All" element but doesn't click it unless I put a sleep before the click. I don't like using the sleep property in this scenario. What would you recommend instead of implicit waits

Comment: Once `ImplicitylyWait` is set, when you try to find an `element` forever after in your tests, it'll wait that long until it can **find** it, not the same thing as it waiting until it can **click** it. The page might still be changing, or the element is invisible, etc... Use an **explicit** wait instead. Something like `new WebDriverWait(session, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(update.FindElementByName("All"))`. If you add the problem to the question and this works, I'll add as an answer. Things might be different for WinApp, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: Here are some [existing `ExpectedConditions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) you can use, although you can use custom conditions with `WebDriverWait` as well.

Comment: @mrfreester I will try this.. Should I set ImplicitlyWaits when on my TestInitialize and then before my "All" should I use  
Once ImplicitylyWait is set, any time you try to find an element forever after in your tests, it'll wait that long until it can find it, which isn't the same thing as it waiting until it can click it, as the page might still be changing, or the element is invisible, etc... Use an explicit wait instead. Something like `new WebDriverWait(session, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementTo‌​BeClickable(update.F‌​indElementByName("Al‌​l"))`

Comment: I used to set an **implicit wait** in my setup scripts, but I found I would get subtle timing errors and instead I've been only using **explicit** waits. For the most part I put those in some type of base method so I can use them easily everywhere in my code. If you never set an **implicit** wait, basically an exception is thrown the moment you try to find an element that isn't on the page.

Comment: In answer to your last question, yes you should do the **explicit wait** right before the step you need to wait for, in this case you need to make sure you can click the **all** button before you try to click it.

Comment: Ok I think I'm starting to understand. Could you show be an example of your base class and how you would use it in your tests. I will except this as the solution :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148523/discussion-between-craig-gallagher-and-mrfreester).

Comment: I was looking at the object model and tried setting one up however I then went to use `PageFactory.InitElements(driver,powerPoint)` and I got an exception saying `Type of member 'WindowsElement' is not IWebElement or IList<IWebElement>` is there anything I can do to allow a WindowsElement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, you mentioned the issue with the code was that `all` wasn't clickable unless you put in a sleep.

Use an **explicit wait**. Something like:

```
new WebDriverWait(session, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
    .Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementTo‌​BeClickable(update.F‌​indElementByName("Al‌​l"))
```

Things might be a bit different for the **WinApp** Driver, but that's the basic idea.